# How to update ViewModel only after validation

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I'm trying to build users Grid functionality with dialog for editing user details.
here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <script src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/SteveSanderson/knockout/knockout-   2.1.0.js"></script>
 <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel ="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js">  </script>
 <meta charset=utf-8 />
 <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
users:<hr/>
  <div data-bind="foreach:users">
  <div><span data-bind="text:firstname"></span>&nbsp;<a href="#" data- bind="click:EditUser">edit</a></div><hr>
   </div>

   <div id="dialog" style="display:none" data-bind="with:selectedUser">
      <input type="text" data-bind="value:firstname" name="firstname"/>
     <button data-bind="click:validate">save</button>
 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

here is my JS:

```
var userVM=function(nm){
  this.firstname=ko.observable(nm); 
  this.EditUser=function(u){
     selectedUser(u);
    $("#dialog").dialog();
 }
};
var users=ko.observableArray([new userVM('Sholmo'),new userVM('Ahmed')]) ;

var selectedUser=ko.observable();
 var validate=function (){
 if($('[name="firstname"]').val()==''){

 alert('must enter name');
 //how prevent model updating?
 }
}

ko.applyBindings();
```

my problem is that i want to update user details only **AFTER** "save" button clicked and validation is passed, (now the username updated immediatly after text in input changed) 
here is link to jsbin: http://jsbin.com/epocov/1/edit

Answer (score 1):

Knockout hooks into events on the input box so that the viewmodel is updated before focus ever gets to the button.  Thus, it doesn't matter what you put in the validate function - it's too late!  But you probably already figured that out...

I would recommend looking at one of the third party plugins for Knockout that can help you with validation or deferred updates:

- Knockout Validation - https://github.com/ericmbarnard/Knockout-Validation
- Deferred Updates - https://github.com/mbest/knockout-deferred-updates

Comment: thanks for this usefull plugins... BUT! as i understand, thosse validations cannot prevent the users details in the grid of being changed (which i must avoid until save button pressed and validation passed) Thanks again - i will use those plugins for other scenerios

Answer (score 0):

Make use of [writeable computed observable](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html#writeable_computed_observables), and put your validation in the write function.

For example:

```
function MyViewModel() {
    this.firstName = ko.observable('Planet');
    this.lastName = ko.observable('Earth');

    this.fullName = ko.computed({
        read: function () {
            return this.firstName() + " " + this.lastName();
        },
        write: function (value) {
            //**Validate here**
            var lastSpacePos = value.lastIndexOf(" ");
            if (lastSpacePos > 0) { // Ignore values with no space character
                this.firstName(value.substring(0, lastSpacePos)); // Update "firstName"
                this.lastName(value.substring(lastSpacePos + 1)); // Update "lastName"
            }
        },
        owner: this
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but for  some reason i keep get compilation error when i trying to put computed with { read: wirte: } as parameter, may be the reason is ko version?

Comment: @happyZZR1400: Yep it might be the reason. Computed are relatively new. Are you using an old version?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all who tried to help, it  seems i came with my own solution...
this is good for me because in this way the edited user details in the grid cannot change until "save" button clicked and validation passed:
here is my solution:
JS:

```
   ko.bindingHandlers.updateWhenValid = {

        init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
    $(element).val(ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()));
        },
        update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
          var value = valueAccessor();
          var valueUnwrapped = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value);
          $('button').click(function(){
            if($(element).val()!=''){ 
               value($(element).val()); 
               $("#dialog").dialog('close');
            }
            else{ 
             value(valueUnwrapped);
            }  
          });   
        }
    };

    var userVM=function(nm){
    var self=this;  

      this.firstname= ko.observable(nm);

      this.EditUser=function(u){


        selectedUser(u);
        $("#dialog").dialog();
      };


    }; 
    var users=ko.observableArray([new userVM('Shlomo'),new userVM('Ahmed')]) ;

    var selectedUser=ko.observable();



    ko.applyBindings();
```

HTML:

```
  users:<hr/>
 <div data-bind="foreach:users">
   <div><span data-bind="text:firstname"></span>&nbsp;<a href="#" data-bind="click:EditUser">edit</a></div>
  <hr>
</div>


<div id="dialog" style="display:none" data-bind="with:selectedUser">

  <input type="text" data-bind="updateWhenValid:firstname" />



<button >save</button>

</div>
```

This way the original value (that was before dialog opened) stays in case validation failed
  here you can see working demo:

http://jsbin.com/epocov/9/edit